# ngImgCrop get src with php

Tags: php, angularjs

what s the better way to get cropped img src (made with ngImgCrop) with php?

It give me back a base64 img..

The image is something like that:

```
<img ng-src="data:image/png;base64;................"/>
```

I tryed something like this:

```
function base64_to_jpeg($base64_string, $output_file) {

    $ifp = fopen($output_file, "wb"); 

    $data = explode(',', $base64_string);

    fwrite($ifp, base64_decode($data[1])); 
    fclose($ifp); 

    return $output_file; 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the leading "data:image/png;base64," before performing base64_decode on the string representing the new image